# how to find sequences of words in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a big text file like this example.txt:
http://www.fullbooks.com/The-Jacket-Star-Rover-1.html
with awk :

```
cat example.txt | awk '{ print substr($0, index($0,$3)) }' | tr -sc "[A-Z][a-z][0-9]'" '[\012*]' | awk -- 'first!=""&&second!="" { print first,second,$0; } { first=second; second=$0; }' | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | head -n20
```

the output is a top 20 ranking of the three consecutive most recurring words:

```
 13 in the jacket
 11 I was a
 10 of the Yard
 10 me in the
  8 Captain of the
  7 times and places
  7 the Captain of
  7 in the prison
  7 in the dungeons
  7 in San Quentin
  7 I had been
  6 other times and
  6 hours in the
  6 are going to
  5 twenty four hours
  5 to take me
  5 the rest of
  5 the forty lifers
  5 the Board of
  5 that I had
```

Starting with:

```
raw=open('examples.txt')
text=raw.read().replace('\n', '')
words = text.split()
...............
```

how obtain the same with python3?

Comment: words or phrases?

Comment: can you explain better also for the persons who doens't know awk and his syntax?

Answer (score 4):

It's a nice variation of computing the frequency of words, but not that different. I would:

- read the file and split like you did
- create triplets and feed them to `collections.Counter` (using `tuple` type so it's hashable)
- filter/sort to display the ones above 5 occurrences

like this:

```
import collections

with open('example.txt') as raw:
    words = raw.read().split()

c = collections.Counter(tuple(words[i:i+3]) for i in range(len(words)-3))
for x in sorted([(k,v) for k,v in c.items() if v>=5] ,key = lambda x : x[1],reverse=True):
    print(x)
```

Note that splitting using just `str.split()` doesn't work well when there's punctuation (because for instance `"Hello, World"` splits into `"Hello,"` and `"World`), so we would be better off with a regex split on non alphanum char:

```
words = [x for x in re.split("\W",raw.read()) if x]
```

I get this result (more occurrences than with naive `str.split`):

```
(('in', 'the', 'jacket'), 19)
(('of', 'the', 'Yard'), 13)
(('Captain', 'of', 'the'), 12)
(('I', 'was', 'a'), 12)
(('me', 'in', 'the'), 11)
(('in', 'the', 'prison'), 11)
(('in', 'the', 'dungeons'), 10)
(('hours', 'in', 'the'), 9)
(('in', 'San', 'Quentin'), 9)
(('I', 'don', 't'), 8)
(('He', 'was', 'a'), 8)
(('are', 'going', 'to'), 8)
(('I', 'had', 'been'), 7)
(('I', 'have', 'been'), 7)
(('in', 'order', 'to'), 7)
(('times', 'and', 'places'), 7)
(('five', 'pounds', 'of'), 7)
(('and', 'I', 'have'), 7)
(('the', 'Captain', 'of'), 7)
(('Darrell', 'Standing', 's'), 6)
(('I', 'did', 'not'), 6)
(('five', 'years', 'of'), 6)
(('Warden', 'Atherton', 'and'), 6)
(('Board', 'of', 'Directors'), 6)
(('thirty', 'five', 'pounds'), 6)
(('that', 'I', 'had'), 6)
(('pounds', 'of', 'dynamite'), 6)
(('other', 'times', 'and'), 6)
(('of', 'San', 'Quentin'), 5)
(('the', 'forty', 'lifers'), 5)
(('and', 'Captain', 'Jamie'), 5)
(('I', 'Darrell', 'Standing'), 5)
(('in', 'the', 'dungeon'), 5)
(('going', 'to', 'take'), 5)
...
```

Optionally, we could get a different result by converting words to lowercase, in order to merge words starting a sentence (`"in the woods"` vs `"In the woods"`)

Comment: be sure to use the second split method (using regex), because the first one (the one you used) is too naïve with punctuation

Comment: I delete punctuation with: for k in '-.,&()<>‘!—\'#?@|.[]“”ʼ/:‘’;«-»,"’\%':
            line=line.replace(k, " ")

Comment: yeah that works too even if not very performant :) in that case use `string.punctuation`. Regexes are very good at this too.

Answer (score 0):

you could try this simple implementation:

```
import re

frequency={}
with open('example.txt') as raw:
    words = [word.lower() for word in re.split("\W",raw.read()) if word]

for index, word in enumerate(words):
    if index < (len(words)-2):
        triplet = (word, words[index+1], words[index+2])
        if triplet in frequency:
            frequency[triplet] += 1
        else:
            frequency[triplet] = 1

for triplet, rank in frequency.items():
    print(triplet,str(rank))
```